# Фильтр по таблице sql

Tags: python, django

Как на странице сайта сделать фильтр по каталогу из базы sql? - одна таблица с десятком колонок.

поиск - выбор значения из нескольких колонок и вывод результата

мнеб пример модельки работающей, у самого получается хрень, а найти ничего не могу.

вот очень похожая проблема но ответ я не понял

чтобы django знал, что помимо дефолтной базы надо пользоваться еще одной, внес соответствующие изменения в файл settings.py:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/path/to/folder/mydb.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'clients': {
        'NAME': 'clients',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root'
    }
}

база клиентов состоит из одной таблицы со столбцами:
     ID | NAME | CARD | и т.д.
     1 | vasya | 1234 | … 
     2 | petya | 2344 | …
…

добавление новых и редактирование старых строк для данной бд не потребуется.
меня интересуют столбцы NAME и CARD. как нетрудно догадаться NAME - это владелец CARD.

а теперь у меня наступает ступор…

1. для работы с бд клиентов мне требуется в models.py создавать class Clients?

...
    class Clients(models.Model):
         ID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         NAME = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         CARD = models.CharField(max_length=50)
...

2. требуется ли создавать для каждого столбца из таблицы свое поле, если меня интересуют только NAME и CARD?

и возможно ли как-то получить их не вбивая руками, там очень много колонок?

3. как объявить для django, что класс Clients - это таблица из бд clients, а не из бд default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать клас с необходимыми полями нужно,
Можешь не вбивать, для выборки используй Client.objects.using('clients').all()

Comment: Client.objects.using('clients').all() кстати не работает, а срабртало во ето    ids = AutoParsingMan.objects.values_list('marka', flat=True).filter()
 art = list(set(ids))

Comment: и 2ю базу пришлось снести так и не научил пользоваться 2я сразу

Comment: Я из доков брал, у себя проверил работает нормально.